# Magento 2 Adding a custom block template to CMS page

Tags: magento2, blocks, template, custom

I'm struggling including my custom module/block template into a static CMS page.

Here's my block code:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_slider_block" template="Custom_Slider::slider.phtml" />
```

How would I implement this in a static CMS page?

Edit:

I've added a block file with the following code:

```
<?php
 namespace Custom\Slider\Block;

 class Slider extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
 {
   public function _prepareLayout()
  {
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
   }
 }
```

and changed my block call to:

```
{{block class="Custom\Slider\Block\Slider" template="Custom_Slider::slider.phtml"}}
```

But now I get the error:

> Error filtering template: Invalid block type: Custom\Slider\Block\Slider

Edit 2:

Got it working, realised I hadn't included a registration.php file to actually enable the module.

Comment: What is your Block class ?

Comment: Do you mean this? namespace Custom\Slider\Block;

Comment: what is path you have for slider.phtml in your module ?

Comment: Custom/Slider/view/frontend/templates/slider.phtml

Comment: code looks right according to path {{block class="Custom\Slider\Block\Slider" template="Custom_Slider::slider.phtml"}}

Comment: Keeps giving me the error that it's a invalid block type

Comment: can you check app/etc/config.php file ? is there Custom_Slider =1 ?

Comment: Can you post custom_slider module file's path?

Comment: Custom/Slider/view/frontend/templates/slider.phtml, /Custom/Slider/Block/slider.phtml

Comment: Where did you put the code `<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_slider_block" template="Custom_Slider::slider.phtml" />`? In which file??

Answer (score 3):

Try the code below

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Custom_Slider::slider.phtml"}}
```

Comment: I tried your solution Richard and got this error: Error filtering template: Invalid template file: 'Custom_Slider::slider.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'magento\framework\view\element\template_0'

Comment: Just a couple of questions,
1) What is the name of your custom Module
2) Do you have a template called Slider.phtml file ?

Comment: The module is called Custom_Slider, Custom being the vendor. I do have a template called slider.phtml, lower case "s" which sits in Custom/Slider/view/frontend/templates/